# Update label with filename while reading files

Tags: user-interface, label, filenames

I designed a query executer in c #, which allows you to select multiple files (. Sql) and run these queries on multiple databases, selected from a list.
Because this process sometimes takes a long time, I would like some information to the user. In my code, I walk each database first, and for each data base, I walk all the files (. Sql) and I execute them.
In my form I have two labels, I would like to show the current database, and in the other, display the file which is running.
This is already done, the problem is that the labels are not updated, the form is frozen, I have understood that I have to use threads, but not how.
Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                String bd = listBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();

                this.textBD.Text = bd; //UPDATE CURRENT DATABASE LABEL

                bd = bd.Replace("CL25DEMAYO.", "");

                string ConnStrng = "Data Source=CL25DEMAYO;Initial Catalog=" + bd + "; User Id=sa;Password=190205;";

                try
                {
                    this.SqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnStrng);
                    this.SqlConn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }



                for (int e = 0; e < listBoxArchivos.Items.Count; e++)
                {
                    String archi = listBoxArchivos.Items[e].ToString();

                    this.textScript.Text = archi; //UPDATE CURRENT FILE LABEL

                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(archi);
                    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(script, SqlConn);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                SqlConn.Close();
            }
```

would be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved using BackgroundWorker, and updating the labels by the method invoke().